# Saving current page of view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, orientation

I have a view pager on portrait mode. On landscape mode I have completely different layout. After coming back to portrait from landscape, I want to see last seen page of viewpager. But always first page is on the screen.

Here are my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static ViewPager pager=null;
    public static FragmentAdapter adapter;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delict);
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
                mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Changed to page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    }
                });
            }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delict, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            if(pager!=null){
                outState.putInt("PAGE", pager.getCurrentItem());
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if(pager!=null){
         pager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("PAGE"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you only construct the ViewPager in portrait mode?

Comment: It's the design of the application. For landscape mode, application design is completely different.

Comment: Fair enough, would be simpler to check if pager is null after `findViewById(R.id.pager)` I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not have my IDE open at the moment, so syntax corrections might be needed:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
  bundle.putInt("currentItem", pager.getCurrentItem());
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("currentItem", 0));
    }
}
```