# How to save state of page in viewpager in multiple viewpager inside listview?

Tags: android

i created multiple Viewpager inside listview but when i scroll my viewpager page state is change i dont know how to save state of all viewpager inside in listview.please help me.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you need to check this out:

http://github.com/hanks-zyh/ViewPager-Listview-item-Viewpager-

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in this example in when i scroll down my previous Viewpager page is change or its not saving state of previous Viewpager.

Comment: Try something like on the answer below but using ViewPager inside listview row is very uncommon. If you are trying to make swipe then you should use fragments. They have implemented methods for saving states.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554054/saving-current-page-of-view-pager